# MySQL Unknown error: -1 when renaming table of 3GB (no foreign keys)

Tags: mysql, laravel

In Laravel I'm building a Job which imports a 3GB size file. So let's say we want to update the table `properties`.

1. First I clone the table structure of the old table too `properties_import`
2. Then I do a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` on the `properties_import`
3. After that I do `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS properties_backup`
4. Then `RENAME TABLE properties TO properties_backup`
5. Then `RENAME TABLE properties_import TO properties`

This way there should be little to no downtime between the old and the new data. Sadly, on step 5 the following error shows up:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './[database]/properties_import' to './[database]/properties' (errno: -1 - Unknown error: -1)
```

When I called the Job from command line this worked fine, but since there have been some changes and the Job has been running from the Queue. The changes have nothing to do with the queries I'm executing, so I don't think they are relevant to the problem.

As mentioned in the title. The table has no Foreign Keys. Only 5 Indexes and a Primary Key.

I already tried to do a sleep of 10 seconds after the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` because I thought maybe MySql is still swallowing the data, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: *I already tried to do a sleep of 10 seconds after the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE* Try to add this timegap between steps 4 and 5.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your suggestion, I'm trying it now. Results will be in in about 1,5 hours.

Comment: @Akina Sadly it still did not work. Exact same error.

Comment: Does NOW first 4 steps are completed? Now check: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM properties_backup` (must return a number), `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM properties` (must fail because of 'unknown table'), ensure that all table files in the filesystem are renamed, ensure that you can create properties.ibd file manually. If this is everything true then perform this (except file creation - SQL script cannot delete a file from the filesystem) in your script from MySQL and show the result. PS. I think that the problem is in filesystem latency or caching.